# NPM CLI returns command not found

Tags: npm, inquirer, inquirerjs

I have created a simple CLI to bootstrap projects with inquirer and have successfully published it to NPM. However, when installing it with

```
npm i -g noobject
```

it's successfully loading and installing.
When running

```
noobject
```

in the cmd line, it does return "command not found" and when running

```
npx noobject its returning the following.
```

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-13T17_28_00_374Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried it both on windows 10 and linux ubuntu 20.4.
Here is my index.js: https://sourceb.in/ZGZMWKU8tb

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const fs = require("fs");

// FULL SOURCE TREE: https://github.com/vKxni/noobject

const CURR_DIR = process.cwd();
const CHOICES = fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/templates`);

// Questions asked to the User
const QUESTIONS = [
  {
    name: "project-choice",
    type: "list",
    message: "What project would you like to generate?",
    choices: CHOICES,
  },
  {
    name: "project-name",
    type: "input",
    message: "Project name:",
    validate: (input) => {
      if (/^([A-Za-z\-\_\d])+$/.test(input)) return true;
      else
        return "Project name may only include letters, numbers, underscores and hashes.";
    },
  },
];

// Send a prompt to choose a template
inquirer.prompt(QUESTIONS).then((answers) => {
  const projectChoice = answers["project-choice"];
  const projectName = answers["project-name"];
  const templatePath = `${__dirname}/templates/${projectChoice}`;

  // Create the folder with the project name choosed by the user
  fs.mkdirSync(`${CURR_DIR}/${projectName}`);

  createDirectoryContents(templatePath, projectName);

  console.log(`✅ Successfully created ${projectName}`);
});

const createDirectoryContents = (templatePath, newProjectPath) => {
  const filesToCreate = fs.readdirSync(templatePath);

  filesToCreate.forEach((file) => {
    const origFilePath = `${templatePath}/${file}`;

    const stats = fs.statSync(origFilePath);

    if (stats.isFile()) {
      const contents = fs.readFileSync(origFilePath, "utf8");

      if (file === ".npmignore") file = ".gitignore";

      const writePath = `${CURR_DIR}/${newProjectPath}/${file}`;
      fs.writeFileSync(writePath, contents, "utf8");

      console.log(`⚠️ Created ${writePath}`);

    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      fs.mkdirSync(`${CURR_DIR}/${newProjectPath}/${file}`);

      createDirectoryContents(
        `${templatePath}/${file}`,
        `${newProjectPath}/${file}`
      );
    }
  });
};
```

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "noobject",
  "version": "1.2.8",
  "description": "Project generator written in NodeJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "noobject": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/vKxni/noobject.git",
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "generator",
    "project",
    "noobject"
  ],
  "author": "vKxni",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "noobject": "index.js"
  }
  }
}
```

(As a pastebin: https://sourceb.in/CF4ydtNccG).
I hope anyone can help me so I can bootstrap projects and config files easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're missing a `}` for `repository`, so `bin` is actually inside `repository`. You can see there's a doubled `}` in the second to last line.

```json
{
  "name": "noobject",
  "version": "1.2.8",
  "description": "Project generator written in NodeJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "noobject": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/vKxni/noobject.git",
  /* <----- should be here */
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "generator",
    "project",
    "noobject"
  ],
  "author": "vKxni",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "noobject": "index.js"
  }
  } /* <----- wrong place! */
}
```

If you fix that, it works:

```json
{
  "name": "noobject",
  "version": "1.2.8",
  "description": "Project generator written in NodeJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "noobject": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/vKxni/noobject.git",
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "generator",
    "project",
    "noobject"
  ],
  "author": "vKxni",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "inquirer": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "noobject": "index.js"
  }
}
```